# Consulta SQL VIEW

Tags: sql-server

Bom dia.

Preciso de ajuda para resolver uma questão de consulta na view. Preciso de ajuda para criar esta view.

**Segue a tabela:**

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Controle](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DataHora] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Local] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [PessoaID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PessoaNome] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PessoaDocNumero] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [PessoaGrupo] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Outros1] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Outros2] [varchar](30) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Controle] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Segue o insert:**

```
INSERT INTO Controle (DataHora,Local,PessoaID,PessoaNome,PessoaDocNumero,PessoaGrupo,Outros1,Outros2)VALUES(GETDATE(),'TERREO',1,'MARIA','123456789','VISITANTE','XPTO1', 'XPTO2')
    INSERT INTO Controle (DataHora,Local,PessoaID,PessoaNome,PessoaDocNumero,PessoaGrupo,Outros1,Outros2)VALUES(GETDATE(),'TERREO',1,'MARIA','123456789','VISITANTE','XPTO1', 'XPTO2')
    INSERT INTO Controle (DataHora,Local,PessoaID,PessoaNome,PessoaDocNumero,PessoaGrupo,Outros1,Outros2)VALUES(GETDATE(),'TERREO',1,'MARIA','123456789','VISITANTE','XPTO1', 'XPTO2')
    INSERT INTO Controle (DataHora,Local,PessoaID,PessoaNome,PessoaDocNumero,PessoaGrupo,Outros1,Outros2)VALUES(GETDATE(),'TERREO',1,'JOAO','32333232','FUNCIONARIO','XPTO1', 'XPTO2')
    INSERT INTO Controle (DataHora,Local,PessoaID,PessoaNome,PessoaDocNumero,PessoaGrupo,Outros1,Outros2)VALUES(GETDATE(),'TERREO',1,'JOAO','32333232','FUNCIONARIO','XPTO1', 'XPTO2')
    INSERT INTO Controle (DataHora,Local,PessoaID,PessoaNome,PessoaDocNumero,PessoaGrupo,Outros1,Outros2)VALUES(GETDATE(),'TERREO',1,'JOAO','32333232','FUNCIONARIO','XPTO1', 'XPTO2')
```

Objetivo: Preciso saber a quantidade de registros por PessoaGrupo no mês e ano a ser definido e na consulta abaixo eu tenho o resultado esperado. Até aqui tudo ok.

```
SELECT PessoaGrupo, 'Dia ' + '' + Convert(VARCHAR,day(DataHora)) as Dia, COUNT(*) as Valor
    FROM Controle 
    WHERE ID > 0        
    and month(DataHora) = 05
    and year(DataHora) = 2021
    GROUP BY PessoaGrupo, day(DataHora)
```

retorno:

```
Campo       Dia     valor
FUNCIONARIO Dia 12  3
VISITANTE   Dia 12  3
```

Mas como vou utilizar VIEW é onde estou com problemas. Como faço para retornar apenas as 3 colunas conforme a consulta e poder filtrar por qualquer campo da tabela Controle?

Preciso de ajuda para criar esta view para que eu possa filtrar da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM View_Controle
WHERE PessoaGrupo = 'VISITANTE' 
AND month(DataHora) = 05
AND year(DataHora) = 2021

retorno:

    Campo       Dia     valor
    FUNCIONARIO Dia 12  3
    VISITANTE   Dia 12  3
```

Alguém pode me ajudar com a criação desta view?

Grata

Teles

Answer (score 0):

> Objetivo: Preciso saber a quantidade de registros por PessoaGrupo no
> mês e ano a ser definido e na consulta abaixo eu tenho o resultado
> esperado. Até aqui tudo ok.

Visto que na sua consulta, já obteve o resultado esperado, para a criação da `view` você precisa acrescentar no `select` os campos que serão usados na cláusula `where` visto que a consulta referenciando essa `view` passa a considerá-la como uma tabela.
Acrescentei os campos `month(DataHora) mes` e `year(DataHora) ano`, colocando esses campos também no `group by`. Você poderia colocar apenas o campo `DataHora` como campo e fazer as operações tendo esse campo como referência, mas aconselho simplificar logo os campos de forma a facilitar a consulta futura, dispensando assim operações de transformação de resultados sobre a `view`.

```
create view View_Controle as
SELECT month(DataHora) mes, year(DataHora) ano, PessoaGrupo, 'Dia ' + '' + Convert(VARCHAR,day(DataHora)) as Dia, COUNT(*) as Valor
    FROM Controle 
    WHERE ID > 0        
    GROUP BY PessoaGrupo,  day(DataHora), month(DataHora), year(DataHora)
```

No momento de fazer a consulta na `view` ficaria assim:

```
Select PessoaGrupo, Dia, Valor
  from View_Controle
  where mes = 5
    and ano = 2021
```

Comment: Boa tarde. Clarck Maciel.
Obrigada pela ajuda, mas ainda tenho problemas....
Devo poder filtrar por qualquer campo da tabela Controle, mas o resultado deverá ser apenas as 3 colunas: PessoaGrupo, Dia , Valor

Ex: Como filtrar por PessoaNome like '%MARIA%' sem que esta coluna apareça nos resultados

Inserindo PessoaNome na seleção  sou obrigada a colocar no group by e daí o resultado muda

Comment: *"Devo poder filtrar por qualquer campo da tabela Controle"* se quer ter essa flexibiidade não deveria usar uma view, seria mais fácil utilizar a tabela diretamente

Comment: @NádiaTeles, a `view` utilizada com um `COUNT(*) as Valor` geralmente é utilizada para um recorte de dados específico, pois, geralmente irá utilizar o `Group by` para agrupar por um campo. Fiquei com uma dúvida no exemplo do *`like '%MARIA%' `*, você quer informar PessoaNome e quer que a agregação continue sendo pelo campo `PessoaGrupo`? Já cogitou usar várias `views` conforme sua necessidade? Todos os campos realmente serão alvos de consulta? Se sim, vejo duas possibilidades: 1) Várias views utilizando `union`; 2) Uma função que retorne uma tabela em vez de usar apenas uma `view `.

Comment: Obrigada pelo feedback de todos.
Acabei usando uma store procedure onde tenho mais flexibilidade e resolveu a questão.